# Embedded Jetty jar generation

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I a newbie in jetty and I am getting really frustrated by the embedded mode of Jetty. This is what I am doing. I embed jetty web container in my java application. I create a WebContent folder in the source folder of the project(It is an eclipse project). I have created a web.xml file to handle the servlets. However when I run it in eclipse the application works perfectly but when I build the runnable jar file from eclipse and run the following command java -jar app.jar and try to load the index.jsp page I receive a 404 error message. Please help. Can someone tell me where to put the WebContent folder or how to generate the jar file from eclipse?